# show content based on computer php

Tags: php

So I am using this script in php so that only me and a few other devs can see the website while it is under maintenance

```php
$whitelist = array("xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx","xxx.xxx.xx.xxx");

$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

if(!in_array($ip,$whitelist)){
 include("0maintenance/index.php");
 exit;
}
```

this works fine but we change ip addresses often and it's tedious to constantly have to change the code.

Is there a way in php to get specific information from the computer? Any value that can be gotten with php that never changes?

We have 3 laptops that are our permanent development laptops we would like to make a script that specifically links to only our computers all other computers will see the maintenance page

I have seen some things about combining WMI with php to do something like this but I would like to keep it clean,simple, and pure PHP

Comment: Have you tried with `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']`? That way you could compare against machine names

Comment: looking for something that can is unique

Comment: manually add cookies for the three computers, surprised the IP's change that often do the same thing here on occasion (htaccess is better idea than php)

Comment: I could have more devs in the future so I would much like to get a permanent solution instead of a temporary solution like I have in my code already

Comment: could just add basic Apache authentication in the root, every one could use the same user name password, its simple to set up and quite secure

Comment: thats more tedious then my current set up lol

Comment: its about 5 lines of code in one file added once. with out touching the php. how is that tedious

Comment: bc then we have to put in a password or such everytime we go under maintenance

Comment: all modern browsers will remember that for you, so you only need enter it once.

Comment: if no better options come along I might go with that